# Need assistance regarding app store search ads

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-search-ads

Apple [Docs](http://searchads.apple.com/help/basics/) says:

> Who can use Search Ads
>
> If you’re a developer with an app currently on the app Store for
>   iPhone or iPad in the U.S., or an agency that manages campaigns on
>   behalf of developers, you may be eligible to use Search Ads.

Does it means only developers from U.S are eligible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, currently only US registered developers have the feature access. *(Rumours are it will be globally available after the March '17 event)*